# Granting rights to additional MySQL database causing issues

Tags: mysql

I have a user '`myuser`' and two databases. '`db1`' and '`db2`'.

'`myuser`' already has rights to use `db1` and I wanted to grant him additional permission to use '`db2`' by using the following query:

```
GRANT ALL ON db2.* TO 'myuser'@'localhost';
```

After I ran the grant statement, '`myuser`' lost the connection to the first database '`db1`'

I'm afraid that I used a wrong host name. Instead of 'localhost' I should have used '%'. 
When I do:

```
 select host from mysql.user where user = 'myuser';
```

Now I see two host records `'%'` and '`localhost`' for that user

When I run SHOW GRANT statements I get permissions for different hosts. 'localhost' and '%'.

```
mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'myuser'@'localhost';
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for myuser@localhost                                      |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'localhost'                       |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `beta_version`.* TO 'myuser'@'localhost' |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

and

```
mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'myuser'@'%';
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for myuser@%                                                                                   |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*6ASDFASDFASDF...' 
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `myuser`.* TO 'myuser'@'%'                                                
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

What happened that caused '`myuser`' to not work in my PHP scripts and in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: [`SHOW GRANTS` displays only the privileges granted explicitly to the named account. Other privileges might be available to the account, but they are not displayed.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/show-grants.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL identifies a user by BOTH the username and the host.  When MySQL does the authentication at login, MySQL first looks for a hostname that is an exact match. If it doesn't find an exact match, then it looks for a host containing a '%' wildcard.

When you did the `GRANT ... TO myuser@localhost`, MySQL created a new user (with no password, because there was no `IDENTIFIED BY` given in the statement.

Then what happened, when you attempted to login as `myuser` from the localhost, mysqld tried to find an entry that matched `'myuser'@'localhost'` in the mysql.user table and it found it.  And the session got the privileges assigned to that user.

(To be a little more precise, mysqld doesn't really look at the contents of the mysql.user table, what it really looks at the in-memory structure, which was populated from the table when it was built. A rebuild of the memory structure is triggered by a GRANT, a REVOKE or a FLUSH PRIVILEGES statement.)

What was happening BEFORE you added that new user, mysqld was looking for an exact match on user and hostname, and didn't find one. But it did find an entry with the '%' wildcard, so it matched to that, so the session got all the privileges granted to the 'myuser'@'%' user.

---

The two users  `'u'@'%'` and `'u'@'localhost'` are separate and distinct from each other. Privileges must be granted to each user individually.  Any privileges granted to `'u'@'%'` apply ONLY to that user and NOT to `'u'@'localhost'`.

Comment: So it sounds like I should delete a record from `mysql` table where `user = 'myuser' and host='localhost'`  This will get me back to my original state?  Then I can run the query to grant privs again but this time use `'%'` as host.  Does this sound okay or I shouldn't be messing around with mysql table?

Comment: `mysql.user` table that is

Comment: Just removing a user by running a DELETE command doesn't work. I had to go through Plesk and remove and re-add that user. I'm guessing there were additional statements in the background that had to run in order to give user correct permissions.

Comment: @dev.e.loper: deleting the row from the `mysql.user` table is a first step, that needs to be followed by a `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` statement; that tells MySQL to re-read the contents of the `mysql.*` tables. (The `GRANT` and `REVOKE` statements make changes to the mysql.* tables and automatically do the `FLUSH PRIVILEGES`.)

Comment: I granted privs to 'myuser'@'%' for a new database by doing: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON 'db2'.* TO 'myuser'@'%' ` However, when I try to run an insert, it says `INSERT command denied to user 'myuser'@'localhost' for table 'MYTABLENAME'`

Comment: @dev.e.loper: Those are two DIFFERENT users.  The `myuser@localhost` is SEPARATE AND DISTINCT from `myuser@%`.  The fact that the username portion of those identifiers is the same matters NOT ONE WHIT to MySQL... they are SEPARATE users.  One of those usernames might as well be `jjones@appserver`, when it comes to granting privileges.  When you grant privileges to `myuser@%`, that has NO EFFECT whatsoever on the privileges granted to `jjones@appserver` or to `myuser@localhost`.

Comment: I understand that but like you said: "MySQL first looks for a hostname that is an exact match. If it doesn't find an exact match, then it looks for a host containing a '%' wildcard."  So there isn't a myuser@localhost then MySQL should find myuser@% and use that. Correct?

Comment: Yes, if there is no exact match found for `myuser@localhost`, then MySQL will look for a wild card match. But as soon as MySQL finds a match, the session will get the privileges for ONLY that specific user it matched.

Answer (score 0):

[USAGE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_usage) means "no privileges and that is what you have given your user when connecting from localhost.

I think localhost takes precedence over % so when the user is connecting from localhost that is the grant that will be used.

Grant access to both schemas to % (or localhost if that is what you prefer) and it should be clear and work better.