# User can't access a database

Tags: mysql

In my PHP script, I'm accessing two databases `db1` and `db2`.  I have a user `myuser@localhost` that can access `db1` but can't access `db2`.

When selecting from `mysql.user` table, there is one record and the host for that user is a wildcard `%`, there isn't a `localhost` host.

`SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user WHERE user = 'myuser';`  give me:

```
+------------+------+
| user       | host |
+------------+------+
| myuser     | %    |
+------------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Looking at GRANTS for that user, I see same permissions for `db1` as for `db2`

`SHOW GRANTS FOR 'myuser'@'%';`

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for myuser@%                                                                                   |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*7733323232...' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `db1`.* TO 'myuser'@'%'                                                |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `db2`.* TO 'myuser'@'%'                                              |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

In my PHP script I can access `db1` however I get an error: `INSERT command denied to user 'myuser'@'localhost' for table 'HISTORY'`.

It says user is `myuser@localhost` and people suggested adding permission for `myuser@localhost` however, why does this user have access to `db1` and not to `db2`?

Comment: From the error message, I believe you are still logging in as `myuser@localhost` (please show us the output of `SELECT CURRENT_USER();`). If possible, please also show us the output of `SELECT user, host FROM mysql.users WHERE user = 'myuser';`

Comment: @YaK I updated my question with information you asked for.

Comment: Are there other users like `some_login@localhost` on your server? You can see this with `SELECT user, host FROM mysql.users WHERE host = 'localhost';`. If you do not mind, it would be interesting to see the full listing of users on your server (`SELECT user, host FROM mysql.users`).

Comment: have you tried to use distinct connection for each database??

Answer (score 29):

`localhost` does not match `%` in MySQL.  It seems like it should, but in fact it doesn't.  You'd have to separately grant privileges to `user@localhost`, both for the `USAGE` privilege, and for the privileges on each database.

Or you can connect as `user@127.0.0.1` which *does* match `%`.  Using the IP address for localhost seems like it should work identically to localhost, but it doesn't.  You need to have two lines in the `mysql.user` table (and also in the `mysql.db` table in your case) to enable both.

To demonstrate the difference between localhost and 127.0.0.1:

Connecting as `mysql -h localhost` uses the UNIX socket interface, and bypasses TCP/IP.  This can be slightly better for performance, but it has the effect on grant matching described above.

You can force a local TCP/IP connection by connecting as `mysql -h 127.0.0.1`.  Then it will pick up the grants you have made to `myuser@%`.

So to get the same user, password, and privileges for both the socket interface and the TCP/IP interface, you'd need to run *all* of the following statements:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*7733323232...'
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*7733323232...'
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `db1`.* TO 'myuser'@'%'
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `db1`.* TO 'myuser'@'localhost'
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `db2`.* TO 'myuser'@'%'
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `db2`.* TO 'myuser'@'localhost'
```

Comment: Where I'm stumped is that there are exact same privileges given to `myuser@%` for db1 and I can write to it. There isn't a `myuser@localhost` that has permission to `db1` and it works.

Comment: @dev.e.loper: Run `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'myuser'@'localhost'`.

Comment: I get `ERROR 1141 (42000): There is no such grant defined for user 'myuser' on host 'localhost'`

Comment: @dev.e.loper: Have you tried connecting with `mysql -h 127.0.0.1` and see if you have privileges to both databases?

Answer (score 6):

If you haven't done that already, you need to run `flush privileges` so that `mysql` knows there was a change and reloads the privileges table for users:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Yup. Did that. I'm still getting the same message.

Comment: You don't need to flush privileges after `GRANT`, it effectively does the flush for you.  You do need to flush privileges after doing a direct INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE against the `mysql` system tables.

Answer (score 2):

This very likely has nothing to do with GRANTs.

A very common reason for having incorrect access rights is **because of default users** that exist in MySQL. Specially ones with `''` for `User` (anonymous users) and/or `Host` in `mysql.user` table. Because of the way MySQL handles [authentication and proxy users](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/proxy-users.html), and the sorting rules used on `mysql.user` table entries, one could end up using an unexpected user than the one they used for authentication.

Use `SELECT USER();` to find out the connecting user that was used during authentication and `SELECT CURRENT_USER();` to find out the **effective user whose privileges apply during the current session**.

And from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connection-access.html

> It is a common misconception to think that, for a given user name, all
>   rows that explicitly name that user are used first when the server
>   attempts to find a match for the connection. This is not true.
>   If you are able to connect to the server, but your privileges are not
>   what you expect, you probably are being authenticated as some other
>   account.

A `mysql.user` table similar to following

```
+-----------+----------+-
| Host      | User     | ...
+-----------+----------+-
| %         | root     | ... (root from any host)
| %         | jeffrey  | ... (jeffrey from any host)
| localhost | root     | ... (root from localhost)
| localhost |          | ... (any user from localhost)
+-----------+----------+-
```

becomes,

```
+-----------+----------+-
| Host      | User     | ...
+-----------+----------+-
| localhost | root     | ...
| localhost |          | ...
| %         | jeffrey  | ...
| %         | root     | ...
+-----------+----------+-
```

whenever the server reads the user table into memory, in order to handle multiple matches.
When a client attempts to connect, the server looks through the rows in sorted order and uses the first row that matches the client host name and user name.
Precedence is given as: values (IP address, host name, user name, etc.) > `'%'` > `''`

Most of the time application server/client is running in the same host as the database, causing the host name to be picked up as `localhost` during authentication.
`mysql -u jeffrey` uses `jeffrey@localhost` which gets matched against `''@localhost` instead of `jeffrey@%`.

Executing `$MYSQL_HOME/bin/mysql_secure_installation` will remove anonymous users, while securing the installation, alleviating this unexpected behaviour.

Also check:
  [1] http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=36576 (check comment before last)
  [2] http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69570

Answer (score 2):

Just thought I'd add an answer.  I was trying this on ubuntu.  Tried the grants, flushes, nothing worked (this is immediately after by apt-get install mysql-server).  Just for grins I bounced the server, that worked and my new user can now login.  I did:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

I don't know what that worked, but it did.

Answer (score 1):

You must GRANT privileges also to 'myuser'@'localhost':

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `db1`.* TO 'myuser'@'localhost';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `db2_beta`.* TO 'myuser'@'localhost';
```

Otherwise the anonymous user @localhost created during db install takes precedence among your user with the wildcard hostname (%), as described here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/adding-users.html

Comment: I've done that and [had issues](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13997275/37759). Plus `myuser` seem to have the same GRANT privileges to `db1` and it can read/write to `db1`

Answer (score 0):

According to the mysql manual [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privilege-changes.html):

> If you modify the grant tables indirectly using account-management
>   statements such as GRANT, REVOKE, or SET PASSWORD, the server notices
>   these changes and loads the grant tables into memory again
>   immediately.
>
> If you modify the grant tables directly using statements such as
>   INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE, your changes have no effect on privilege
>   checking until you either restart the server or tell it to reload the
>   tables. If you change the grant tables directly but forget to reload
>   them, your changes have no effect until you restart the server. This
>   may leave you wondering why your changes do not seem to make any
>   difference!

This does seem to be true in most cases. However, in my situation I was working with an Amazon Web Services (AWS) RDS mysql instance.  After many unsuccessful attempts to grant the user permissions I tried a `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` and the database was immediately visible to the user.  If you come across this while looking for a solution on the Amazon Web Services RDS platform you might want to give this a try and see if it helps.

This SO question contains the most complete solutions to this problem and is the first in most search results so I wanted to add this response for anyone using RDS.  Hopefully it will save RDS admins some time.