# MySQL permission issue: User cannot see database despite permission being granted to role

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, permissions, mariadb, access-control

Running as `root` user on the database:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW GRANTS FOR jake@localhost;
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for jake@localhost                                                                                   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT developer TO 'jake'@'localhost'                                                                       |
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'jake'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*intentionallyomitted' |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW GRANTS FOR developer;
+-------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for developer                            |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'developer'               |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `test`.* TO 'developer' |
+-------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.002 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW DATABASES;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| test               |
+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> USE mysql;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
MariaDB [mysql]> SELECT Host, User, is_role, default_role FROM user WHERE User = 'jake' OR User = 'developer';
+-----------+-----------+---------+--------------+
| Host      | User      | is_role | default_role |
+-----------+-----------+---------+--------------+
|           | developer | Y       |              |
| localhost | jake      | N       |              |
+-----------+-----------+---------+--------------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [mysql]> SELECT * FROM roles_mapping WHERE User = 'jake';
+-----------+------+-----------+--------------+
| Host      | User | Role      | Admin_option |
+-----------+------+-----------+--------------+
| localhost | jake | developer | N            |
+-----------+------+-----------+--------------+
1 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Then, after running `sudo systemctl restart mysql`:

```
$ mysql -u jake -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 11
Server version: 10.3.13-MariaDB-1:10.3.13+maria~bionic mariadb.org binary distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT CURRENT_USER;
+----------------+
| CURRENT_USER   |
+----------------+
| jake@localhost |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW DATABASES;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

It seems like I clearly gave the `jake@localhost` user privileges to the test database by giving the `developer` role permissions and then adding the user to that role. However, the user cannot see the database (or the table inside it).

Is this just a silly typo somewhere in my code? What could cause such an issue? One thought I had was that this was a problem related to the `IDENTIFED BY PASSWORD` clause, since it appears only on the `GRANT USAGE` and nowhere else, but I can hardly imagine this causing such an error. There is [a related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011968/user-cant-access-a-database) but since the user is `jake@localhost` everywhere (consistently), neither of the solutions in that thread seem to be the problem. So what gives?

Version:

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.13-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
```

Comment: What does `SELECT CURRENT_ROLE;` give when you log in as `jake@localhost` i assume the result is `NULL` ?   as iam pretty sure you still have to grant to role to that MySQL user more or less with `GRANT developer to 'jake'@'localhost'`

Comment: It indeed gives `NULL`. This would indeed explain the problem, but not quite why it occurs. I have edited to include more information about the user and role.

Comment: *"This would indeed explain the problem, but not quite why it occurs."* Yes it does... How should MySQL know that jake is part of the dev team without you telling? Run `GRANT developer to 'jake'@'localhost'` as `root` ? The MySQL user account needs to have a role defined to get the role permissions aswell... Then 'jake'@'localhost' should have the `developer` role which you can check with `SELECT CURRENT_ROLE;` again then it should say `developer`

Comment: I had run this already and ran it again. No change in behavior. I will add contents of roles_mapping table to the question.

Comment: @RaymondNijland note that the `jake@localhost` user always had the `developer` grant.

Comment: Yes that was not clear from the start..

Answer (score 0):

After some additional fidgeting I realized that I did not make the role default or set it in the session I was using. Running `SET ROLE developer;` fixed the issue.

Comment: `SET DEFAULT ROLE
    {NONE | ALL | role [, role ] ...}
    TO user [, user ] ...`  might be even better.. -> *"For each user named immediately after the TO keyword, this statement defines which roles become active when the user connects to the server and authenticates, or when the user executes the SET ROLE DEFAULT statement during a session. "*

Comment: @RaymonfNijland yes, this is the permanent fix. Thanks for all the help.