# Does selecting from different database switches user?

Tags: php, mysql

In the following code I get output that tells me that current user is `myuser@%` and then second query will give me an error saying `myuser@localhost` was denied INSERT permission.

```
$query = "SELECT CURRENT_USER();"
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($result))
{
    $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo(" current user - ". $data['CURRENT_USER()'] . "\n"); //current user - myuser@%
}


$query = "INSERT INTO DIFF_DATABASE.HISTORY (DATA) VALUES (\"" . $data. "\")";
if(mysql_query($query) == false)
{
    echo(mysql_error()); // INSERT command denied to user 'myuser'@'localhost' for table 'HISTORY'
}
```

It looks like there is a switch of MySQL user from `myuser@%` to `myuser@localhost` How does this happen? I'm guessing this is because I'm selecting from a different database in the second query.

Comment: `%` can appear as the hostname in a grant, it's a wildcard that means any host. But I don't think it can be part of the actual user connection, that always name or IP of the client host. I'm not sure why `CURRENT_USER()` is returning it in the first place.

Comment: When I select users from `mysql.user` table where `user=myuser`,  I only see `myuser` with host of `%`

Comment: Right, that's where grants are stored, and that's a wildcard. But the actual user that you're logged in as has a real hostname.

Comment: Since `%` is a wildcard shouldn't giving grant rights to `myuser@%` give grant rights to any host like `localhost`?

Comment: Yes, it should. What does `show grants for myuser@%;` show?

Comment: `GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*7733323232...' 
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `db1`.* TO 'myuser'@'%'                                                   GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `DIFF_DATABASE`.* TO 'myuser'@'%'`

Comment: And `diff_database` from your question is one of `db1` or `db2_beta`?

Comment: `show grants for myuser@localhost`

Comment: It says 'no such grant defined'. When I tried giving grants to myuser@localhost, I got into [other issues](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13997275/37759)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The value of CURRENT_USER() can differ from the value of USER().

```
mysql> SELECT USER();
        -> 'davida@localhost'
mysql> SELECT * FROM mysql.user;
ERROR 1044: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to
database 'mysql'
mysql> SELECT CURRENT_USER();
        -> '@localhost'
```

> The example illustrates that although the client specified a user name
>   of davida (as indicated by the value of the USER() function), the
>   server authenticated the client using an anonymous user account (as
>   seen by the empty user name part of the CURRENT_USER() value). One way
>   this might occur is that there is no account listed in the grant
>   tables for davida.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_current-user